# emacs auctex 11.88: Symbol's value as variable is void: LaTeX-dialect

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I have a problem in using auctex 11.88 with emacs:

Whenever I try to open a .tex-File the following error message appears:

```
Loading /home/schmidt/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.88.2/style/wrapfig.elc...
load: Symbol's value as variable is void: LaTeX-dialect
```

When I try to load the file a second time, everything works. It seems to me that latex.el where this variable is set, does not work correctly when opening the file for the first time.
This is how I initialize auctex in my .emacs file:

```
(load "tex-site.el" nil t t)
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which emacs version are you using ? If you have Emacs 24 you should install it using the package manager: (require 'package) (package-initialize) (package-install 'auctex)

Comment: You don't need any of those two `load`s you have in your `~/.emacs` since the package is installed via ELPA and hence is automatically setup for you.

Comment: I am using Emacs 24 and I have installed the package via the package manager. Removing the two lines from my .emacs file did not solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have other installation of AUCTeX on your system?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I could fix this problem by removing the line

```
(tool-bar-mode -1)
```

from my .emacs.